# How to fix a broken dura Ace shifter( body)?

Tags: shimano

[Crack just beneath the lever.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMYmJ.jpg) 
As you can see that my dura Ace shifter is cracked but but interesting part is that it works perfectly fine but the problem which I face while sprinting is the play which is in the right shifter.
It was cracked when I was crashed during a mass start.![image]
People please I would really like to know you opinion. Any kind of glue or paste which I could use to get it back together.

Comment: Wrap it with tape.  As to glue, you could consider wrapping with fiberglass strips and coating with epoxy.  Plain glue would not last very long.

Comment: Plastics are notoriously hard to glue. Daniel has a good idea about taping with fiberglass- or carbon-reinforced tape but that'd just be a stop-gap and might build up bulk around the handles. You could weld it back together by melting the plastic, but given that it's a critical safety item, I agree with Calvin that you should just get a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the critical job of your brakes in helping you race safely, the wiser action is to replace your equipment rather than try to fix this type of break.  The shifting and brake system may work now but the system is compromised and can fail at any time regardless of how you patch it up.  It's hard to swallow, for sure, but you are putting yourself and those you are racing/riding with at risk by continuing to use broken equipment.

Depending on the age of your shifters, Shimano equipment can be mixed and matched so if the price of replacement at the highest level is too much you can look into replacing with Ultegra or 105 without noticing a great dip in performance.

Comment: Sir could you suggest me some online sites else then wiggle ,bike 24 ,chain reaction, probike kit, bike discount.de! From where I could get the shifter

Comment: Depending on where you live I may not be able to give you a good recommendation.  A good direction for you is to ask your question as a separate post - you'll get more visibility to your question that way as well.